# Dockerfile is caching an old version of a generated file

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, yarnpkg

I'm working on a Dockerfile with a multi-stage build. The general idea is to build the binary for the backend, build the javascript bundle for the frontend, and then put these two things in a final container for the app.

Here's the docker file:

```
# go binary
FROM golang:alpine as build-go
RUN apk --no-cache add git bzr mercurial
ENV D=/go/src/github.com/tamuhack-org/quack
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html
RUN go get -d -v github.com/gorilla/handlers
RUN go get -d -v github.com/gorilla/mux
COPY ./main.go $D/main.go
COPY ./frontend/dist $D/frontend/dist
RUN rm -rf $D/frontend/dist/index.html
RUN rm -rf $D/frontend/dist/index.js
RUN cd $D && go build -o main && cp main /tmp/

# ui
FROM node:alpine AS build-node
RUN mkdir -p /src/ui
COPY ./frontend/package.json /src/ui/
RUN cd /src/ui && yarn install
COPY ./frontend /src/ui
# Replace the dev instance of index.html with the prod version.
RUN rm -rf /src/ui/dist/index.html
RUN mv /src/ui/dist/index-prod.html /src/ui/dist/index.html
RUN cd /src/ui && yarn build

# final
FROM alpine
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /app/server/
COPY --from=build-go /tmp/main /app/server/
COPY --from=build-node /src/ui/dist /app/server/frontend/dist
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["./main"]
```

What I've noticed is that when I update the frontend source code and build the docker container, the new version of the container doesn't update with the new bundle. Are there any obvious errors in the Dockerfile that may be the reason for why I'm not seeing any file changes? If I run `yarn build` locally, the bundle is accurate, but the docker container seems to be caching an older version. Thoughts?

Comment: when you run build with `--no-cache` flag target image is updated?

Comment: How do you check if the file has changed? maybe your tricked by browser cache? the default file server in go sets the Last-Modified header based on the file which can make browser do quite aggressive caching

Comment: @gCoh I’ve been using that argument and it doesn’t help :(.

Comment: @Mattias I didn’t think of that, but every time I check for changes, I do it in an incognito window. Wouldn’t that take care of that scenario?

Comment: Hmm not sure if incognito shares cache or not... hopefully not. In chrome you can disable cache in the network tab in developer tools.

Comment: After you build the image, how are you running the new container?

Comment: @BMitch I'm uploading it to google container registry, and then update the image of a deployment that I'm running (I can be more specific if you think it'd be helpful)

Comment: @MattiasWadman Incognito doesn't share a cache. I'm going to try changing the name of the javascript file shortly (which will force a cache miss). Will keep this thread up to date.

Comment: @JayK. OK! A neat trick is to add `?blablasomething` after a static file URL to cause cache miss